# no match for call to ‘(std::vector<foo>) (std::vector<foo>::iterator&)’

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I've got a class foo, and have created a vector for it using this code

```
std::vector<foo> fooVector;
```

I also have an iterator using this code

```
std::vector<foo>::iterator locator;
```

now I'm getting this error

```
foo.cpp:29:25: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<foo>) (std::vector<foo>::iterator&)’
```

and the corresponding line is

```
if(fooVector(locator).getBoo() + (insertBar.geBoo()) < 4000)
```

as far as I can tell I'm using the iterator correctly?

I'm not sure what is wrong with how I'm using it?

Answer (score 0):

`fooVector(locator)` what do you want to express by this?

`fooVector` is a variable not a function.

Answer (score 0):

If the `locator` iterator is correctly initialized before using it then you should change your code to

```
if(locator->getBoo() + (insertBar.geBoo()) < 4000)
```